# Using Pose Library for NLA (non-linear animations) causing distortions

Tags: animation, armature, rigify, pose-mode, nla-editor

I've saved a few hand poses using Blender's Asset Library and hoping to use them in some animations. But when I use them as keyframes and Push it down to an NLA, the fingers become distorted and I can't figure out what is causing the problems.

I've included a video of the process here. Here's also what I did along with screenshots:

1. From the Pose Library when I click "Apply Pose", I can see that it applies normally on the model.

[image: Hand fist from Pose Library applied onto model]

2. I then "Select Pose Bones" to only select the ones I want to affect and add a Keyframe > Rotation. You can see it's added in the Action Editor as well.

[image: Add Pose Bones as a Keyframe]

3. I push down the track into a new NLA and rename it as hand_fist.
4. When I play the action, the fingers come out messed up.

[image: Fist messed up after pushing down to a new NLA track]

I've tried re-doing this a few times with no luck. Hoping someone can help me out!!! Thanks so much!

Comment: So as a different experiment what happens when you save all the bones at once?  Do you have any intuition that you may be combining old data and new data in ways that you did not intend?

Comment: If you have only a small investment of time previously,  I would also consider deleting all actions and trying a new fresh experiment.  Technically, I cannot see that all fingers are well placed in the first image.  Fist is a difficult position to see.  Needs a few views to see all.